# cmake ist putting static library (c++fs) not at the end in linker command

Tags: c++, linker, linker-errors, std-filesystem

I have the problem, that linking to `stdc++fs` (std::exeperimental::filesystem) is not going to work.

Essentially I have the following to invocations for my target:

```
target_link_libraries(${TARGETNAME} PRIVATE "c++fs" "c++experimental")
target_link_libraries(${TARGETNAME} PRIVATE MyCoreDeps)
```

which results in

```
/usr/local/opt/llvm-7.0/bin/clang++  -g  -L/usr/local/opt/llvm-7.0/lib 
-Wl,-rpath,/usr/local/opt/llvm-7.0/lib  
-fsanitize=address 
CMakeFiles/ExecutionGraphTest-ExecutionTree.dir/src/main_ExecutionTree.cpp.o 
CMakeFiles/ExecutionGraphTest-ExecutionTree.dir/src/TestFunctions.cpp.o  
-o ExecutionGraphTest-ExecutionTree 
-Wl,-rpath,...some..paths... 
../lib/libExecutionGraph-CoreForTests-dbg.so.1.0.3
../lib/libgtestd.a
 ../lib/libgmock_maind.a 
-lc++fs -lc++experimental 
../../buildExternal/install/fmt/lib/libfmt.a
../../buildExternal/install/rttr/lib/librttr_core.so.0.9.7
../../buildExternal/install/flatbuffers/lib/libflatbuffers.a
../../buildExternal/install/crossguid/lib/libcrossguid.a /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libuuid.so 
../lib/libgmockd.a 
../lib/libgtestd.a 
-pthread
```

Which fails because `-lc++fs` is in the middle of the link command, instead of at the end because its a static library? how can I circumvent this and why is cmake not capable of doing this right, meaning serving the linker with the correct dependencies, what I am doing wrong here?

Output:

```
/usr/bin/ld: ../lib/libExecutionGraph-CoreForTests-dbg.so.1.0.3: undefined reference to `std::experimental::filesystem::v1::__cxx11::path::_M_split_cmpts()'
/usr/bin/ld: ../lib/libExecutionGraph-CoreForTests-dbg.so.1.0.3: undefined reference to `std::experimental::filesystem::v1::__cxx11::path::compare(std::experimental::filesystem::v1::__cxx11::path const&) const'
```

Comment: What's the error message? With a static library, the order doesn't have the importance as for shared libraries.

Comment: I think it fails because there's no library named `c++fs`. The name of the library is the full `stdc++fs`. But without seeing the error messages that's just a guess.

Answer (score 3):

Sadly, there was no error message that `-lc++fs` was not used. The correct naming is important: `stdc++fs`

```
target_link_libraries(${TARGETNAME} PRIVATE "stdc++fs" "c++experimental")
```